# Difficult to create formula for this situation

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

My Conditions are:

if h7:h15=="IN" AND k7:k15="YES" then Sum(m7:m5)

My Try:

> =ARRAYFORMULA(if(and(H7:H15="IN",M7:M15="YES"),sum(K7:K15)) // ==> always returns false
>
> =if(And(H7="IN",M7="YES"),sum(K7:K15),"FALSE") // same always false

Am very beginner in spreadsheet!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

As per my comment above, you should be able to utilise sumifs. See attached example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure whether google sheets utilises the sum ifs formula:

SUMIFS(K7:K15,H7:H15,"IN",M7:M15,"YES")

Alternatively, you could use sum and evaluate each row in a separate formula e.g.
IF(AND(H7 = "IN", K7 = "Y"), M7).

Do this for each row and then sum these answers.

Comment: Hi new contributor, welcome to SO site. For solution, i don't want separate formula and evaluation. And your formula not working.

Comment: Why you put "YES" at last?

Comment: That's how the sumifs formula works, it's separated by commas as follows SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, criteria_range2, criteria2...) Hence the YES is your second criteria and therefore appears last

Comment: Google sheets may not work with sumifs formula; give me 5 minutes to look at what it can cope with

Comment: I've added an example screenshot in a separate response - couldn't see a way of adding it into these comments